# how upload files on appfog

Tags: node.js, appfog

I created node.js app on appfog, then I download command prompt and logged in.
But how can I upload some files?
"Finally from within your source code directory:

af update myApp"

how can I set directory or what files to upload?

I would like to upload this http://tutorialzine.com/2012/08/nodejs-drawing-game/ but I didn't find how select downloaded folder and how upload it.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just execute `af update appname` from directory you want to upload, or you can specify upload directory path with `--path` option.

Comment: thanks, but now I am getting this error if I want to login: incompatible character encodings: windows-1250 and utf-8 can you help me?

Comment: I resolved it with downloading older version of rubyinstaller

Comment: HI I am using af update appnam command.. its upload the app but my static folders like images,jade templates and css are not going to uploaded and my URL becomes blank.. Can you please tell me how to upload whole app with static files..